# Exclude files from browserify bundle via config

Tags: angularjs, gulp, browserify

I'm using Browserify as part of a gulp task. The bundle builds, but it pulls in angular because it is being required in some files. I was hoping I could tell browserify that Angular is an external resource. So I attempted

```
var b = browserify ({
external: ['angular', 'jquery', 'etc'],
...
});
```

Unfortunately, Browserify still pulls in angular and other into the bundle. How would one resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the option you are searching for is `exclude`

```
var b = browserify ({
    exclude: ['angular', 'jquery', 'etc'],
    ...
});
```